# Create new array based of two different arrays (match values)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays in JavaScript and I want to re-arrange one based on the order of the first.

**First array:**

```
var arrayOne = [ 
        "5", 
        "1", 
        "2", 
        "4"
    ]
```

**Second array** that I want to re-arrange based on page_id that matches to arrayOne:

```
var arrayTwo = [ 
    {
        "page_id" : "5",
        "page_title" : "About"
    },
    {
        "page_id" : "2",
        "page_title" : "Home"
    }, 
    {
        "page_id" : "4",
        "page_title" : "Contact Us"
    }, 
    {
        "page_id" : "1",
        "page_title" : "Gallery"
    }, 
];
```

**After re-arranged**
I want to re-arrange arrayTwo based on page_id, so once re-arranged the second array will look this like:

```
var arrayTwo = [
    {
        "page_id" : "5",
        "page_title" : "About"
    },
    {
        "page_id" : "1",
        "page_title" : "Gallery"
    }, 
    {
        "page_id" : "2",
        "page_title" : "Home"
    }, 
    {
        "page_id" : "4",
        "page_title" : "Contact Us"
    }, 

];
```

I'm pretty stuck at this point, I've found many sorting 'solutions' on here and Google but they just don't seem to work. I've tried using a for-loop to do this but I didn't really get anywhere. I wouldn't normally ask for help but I've been stuck for a good 3 hours searching.

The match between the first is matched with `page_id` in the second so there's a match that I can use but as mentioned I'm pretty stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the second array into an object - the key will be the page_id, for example:

```
var map = arrayTwo.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b.page_id] = b;
  return a;
}, {});
```

Now we can easily `map` the first array, like:

```
arrayOne.map(x => map[x]);
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/tiyudutasi/edit?js,console

Comment: This solution is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note, how can anybody down vote this? I'm thinking it's because I choose CD..'s solution as opposed to the others. CD's solution is the most simplistic. This community is bitter and elitist, you can't even ask a question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` to iterate `arrayOne`, `Array.prototype.filter()` to match object at `arrayTwo` having `page_id` equal to current `arrayOne` value

```js
var arrayOne = [
  "5",
  "1",
  "2",
  "4"
];

var arrayTwo = [{
  "page_id": "5",
  "page_title": "About"
}, {
  "page_id": "2",
  "page_title": "Home"
}, {
  "page_id": "4",
  "page_title": "Contact Us"
}, {
  "page_id": "1",
  "page_title": "Gallery"
}];

arrayTwo = arrayOne.map(function(id) {
  return arrayTwo.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.page_id === id
  })[0]
});

console.log(arrayTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You first create an "index" that given an object number can return the number:

```
var index = {};
arrayTwo.forEach(function(obj){index[obj.page_id] = obj;});
```

then you can use the index to reorder the objects:

```
var reordered = arrayOne.map(function(id){return arrayTwo[id];});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 2 forEach (one per array)

```
var arrayOne = [
    "5",
    "1",
    "2",
    "4"
]
var arrayTwo = [
    {
        "page_id" : "5",
        "page_title" : "About"
    },
    {
        "page_id" : "2",
        "page_title" : "Home"
    },
    {
        "page_id" : "4",
        "page_title" : "Contact Us"
    },
    {
        "page_id" : "1",
        "page_title" : "Gallery"
    },
];

var result = [];
arrayOne.forEach(item => arrayTwo.forEach(element => { if (item === element.page_id) result.push(element)}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will be more readable.

```
arrayOne.map(id => arrayTwo.find(row => row.page_id === id));
```

If you need to support more browsers, you can use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) instead.

```
arrayTwo.sort((a, b) => arrayOne.indexOf(a.page_id) - arrayOne.indexOf(b.page_id));
```